# Why do symbol categories disappear when unchecked in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, style, categorized-renderer

I am using Qgis 2.18.25

In a vector layer, when using the categorized style, when I uncheck a category the category disappears.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Actually I do not really understand why this change was made.

Why would we want an unchecked category to disappear?

Comment: The same happened here with countries that I unchecked or made invisible. Very confusing that they disappear from the layer panel.

Answer (score 3):

This might be due to `Filter Legend By Map Content` being selected.  It's the fourth icon from the left at the top of the Layers panel (the icon looks like a funnel)